# Trying to install phpmyadmin - getting error 500

Tags: centos, php5

(Using PHP 5.4.15, Apache 2.2, CentOS 6.4 minimal)

I'm having trouble installing phpMyadmin, I followed the [instructions here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install), specifically:

1. I uploaded the phpMyAdmin-*.tar.gz & unzipped it to `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/`
2. Copied config.inc.php & CHMODed it to 600 (I have suexec enabled, though I also tried with 660)

Yet I'm having error 500 whenever I access `http://my-ip-address/phpmyadmin/index.php`

I checked the apache2 logs, I see this error repeated countless times:

`[Fri Jun 07 00:24:26 2013] [error] [client 11.222.33.44] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/_/8thpixel.com/public_html/phpmyadmin/libraries/Header.class.php on line 135`

I checked the source of `Header.class.php` (didn't modify it), line #135 looks like this:

`if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->get('user_preferences') == 'session'
            && ! isset($_SESSION['userprefs_autoload'])`

I checked `$GLOBALS`, there's no `user_preferences` at all!

I've been pulling my hear for two days now, anyone can tell me what's wrong anyway?

Comment: Try the config with 664 to see if it works. Does your apache user own the config file? www-data or apache usually.

Comment: @NathanC: You're a genius! chmodding config.inc.php with 664 did it man, please post this as an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod 664 config.inc.php` should resolve the problem. You may be able to get away with 660 if the config file is owned by the web server's user.